# Deriving variance of Beta distribution using $E[Z^m(1-Z)^n]$

Tags: self-study, variance, beta-distribution

I have been kind of stuck on this exercise for quite a bit:

[image: Bayesian Data Analysis (Gelman), Chapter 2 exercise 15]

I can compute the integral and set the parameters to get the mean.
Now for the variance, I have a feeling there must be some easy way to get it by just choosing the right m and n, but I cannot really think of any.

For the first question I got: $\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} *\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+m)\Gamma(\beta+m)}{\Gamma(\alpha+m+\beta+n)}$

The mean, you can find by just plugging in $m=1,n=0$

Now for the variance the only way I can think of is to use the identity $E(X^2)-E(X)^2$, where we can find $E(X^2)$ by using the parameters $m=2,n=0$ and $E(X)^2$ by squaring the mean.
However this method really does not seem to be taking advantage of the set up, as we could have done it without using $E[Z^m(1-Z)^n]$ and just using moments.

Am I overthinking this exercise or is there a more beautiful solution that eludes me?

Comment: You are presumably reading too much in the question.

Comment: Hint: exploit the results with $n=0.$